# "unsupported get request" for a post that exists and is publicly visible

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The following public post which is visible on the page it was posted (it is not "hidden") is a mystery to me: https://www.facebook.com/Orange.France/posts/833781953305851

i.e., it is not available in the page's /feed edge, and the graph API can't retrieve it either. The following command returns an "unsupported get request":

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/170852259598827_833781953305851?access_token=XXX
```

I tried also the following without much success:

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/833781953305851?access_token=XXX
```

In both cases, I tried the access_token of the page as well a random access_token generated from the graph explorer.

So, the question is: how can I retrieve this post through the FB API ?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think this error is a known bug in the FB API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't retrieve that post via the API - it was made by a user whose data cannot be accessed via the API by any app due to their privacy settings

You can see this by trying to load the poster's details (`https://graph.facebook.com/<username>`- it fails with the same exception)

Such posts will never be accessible via the API, because the person who made the post has explicitly disabled all apps from interacting with them or their posted content

If you want to prevent such users from posting on the page, there's an API-settable option called which will stop this - documentation for how to apply settings to the pages your app manages is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/settings
The specific option you need to enable to prevent platform-opt-out users from posting is called `PLATFORM_OPTOUTS_CAN_POST`

Comment: This appears to be true on a test page+test user account. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is not because of page, but it's because of the author turn the platform off.

You can't query the author basic info via Graph API.

[image]

The author can turn the platform off, so any Graph API query including comments wouldn't include him.

[image]